# Content visibility condition based on date

Tags: conditional-tags

How can I use visibility condition for displaying post no older than 30 days as described here:
https://docs.dynamic.ooo/article/58-visibility-triggers-custom-condition
I try something like this

```
 $date_args =  
            array(
              'key' => 'date',
              'compare' => '>',
              'value' => date("Y-m-d"),
              'type' => 'DATE'
            ),
            array(
              'key' => 'date',
              'compare' => '<=',
              'value' => date("Y-m-d", strtotime("-30 days")),
              'type' => 'DATE'

        ),
    );
    $date_query = new WP_Query( $date_args );
```

or this:

```
$value = get_post_meta (get_the_date( 'l F j, Y' )) ;
if ($value < 30){
Return true;
}
```

but I dont know how achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

To display posts published in the last 30 days, you can pass the "date_query" argument inside WP_Query as follows.

```
$getPosts = new WP_Query(
    array(
        "date_query" => array(
            "column" => "post_date_gmt",
            "after"  => "1 month ago",
        ),
    )
);
```

You can read more about WP_Query on [WP_Query | Class | WordPress Developer Resources](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/)

Comment: Hi, I no need getPost, but condition for displaying  ACF meta field on posts That are no older then 1 month only. Like on screenshot here: https://docs.dynamic.ooo/article/58-visibility-triggers-custom-condition  I try something like this: `$value = get_post_meta (get_the_ID(), 'date' , true);
   if array(
        "date_query" => array(
            "column" => "post_date_gmt",
            "after"  => "1 month ago",
        ),
    ){
    return true
);
}` but This not work.